# How to install a clickonce application on rd session host server

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, remoteapp

I am trying to install a visual basic Windows Forms Application on a Terminal Services (RD Web) server. I put the server in install mode with change user /install, but I still could not get my application to run properly. I thought it should show up on the list of applications when I try to publish it on remoteapp manager.

Then I tried using windows explorer as the container to run the application but still no success.

Is there something I am missing? Please help.

Comment: Wow, my question is a tumbleweed. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. Thank you very much.  It was all a question of folder and file permissions. My application launches properly now and is used by everyone in my organization who uses a computer. I hope I was able to help another person with this solution. Thanks.